# How do I install the sample data after setting up Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to install sample-data after successfully Magento setup. What is the process of installing the sample-data after Magento installation in Magento2?

Answer (score 47):

1. Install sample data modules:

   - Using composer:

     1. Add dependencies to the `composer.json`:

        ```
        composer require magento/module-bundle-sample-data magento/module-widget-sample-data magento/module-theme-sample-data magento/module-catalog-sample-data magento/module-customer-sample-data magento/module-cms-sample-data  magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data magento/module-review-sample-data magento/module-tax-sample-data magento/module-sales-sample-data magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data magento/module-downloadable-sample-data magento/module-msrp-sample-data magento/module-configurable-sample-data magento/module-product-links-sample-data magento/module-wishlist-sample-data magento/module-swatches-sample-data magento/sample-data-media magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data --no-update
        ```
     2. Run:

        ```
        composer update
        ```
   - Using magento:

     1. Deploy sample data:

        ```
        bin/magento sampledata:deploy
        ```
2. Enable sample data modules (it's important!):

   ```
   bin/magento module:enable Magento_CustomerSampleData Magento_MsrpSampleData Magento_CatalogSampleData Magento_DownloadableSampleData Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData Magento_BundleSampleData Magento_ConfigurableSampleData Magento_ThemeSampleData Magento_ProductLinksSampleData Magento_ReviewSampleData Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData Magento_SwatchesSampleData Magento_GroupedProductSampleData Magento_TaxSampleData Magento_CmsSampleData Magento_SalesRuleSampleData Magento_SalesSampleData Magento_WidgetSampleData Magento_WishlistSampleData
   ```
3. Remove old files:

   ```
   rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*
   ```
4. Upgrade magento files:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:upgrade
   ```
5. Recompile files:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```
6. Do reindex:

   ```
   bin/magento indexer:reindex
   ```
7. Deploy static content:

   ```
   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```

Comment: need to run bin/magento setup:di:compile after bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: @hkguile Thank you for information. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Gem Sorry about that, but I did not work with Magento under Windows :( I think all commands are similar, just use a backward slash and correct paths to the executable php.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for your response i tried all possibilities almost 4 days, still error completely sick with Magento 2.3.

Answer (score 44):

download sample data:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Then install sample data:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

http://m4s0.com/install-magento-2-with-sample-data/

Comment: I have got an error message after trying the above code.  "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages." Problem 1
    - magento/sample-data 0.42.0-beta2 requires magento/sample-data-media ~0.42.0-beta1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/sample-data 0.42.0-beta2 requires magento/sample-data-media ~0.42.0-beta1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for magento/sample-data 0.42.0-beta2 -> satisfiable by magento/sample-data[0.42.0-beta2].

Comment: Great answer! The only thing I would add is to remember that when it asks you to login this is not asking for your credentials to magento.com, but you need to generate a public and private key and then use that for the username and password.

Answer (score 10):

You can use command line to install sample data by going to magento 2 root folder. Then,

1. download sample data: `$php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`
2. install sample data: `$php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html

Answer (score 3):

I just ran through this: The sample data won't work if your on the development branch which is the default on github. Grab the master instead.

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/magento/magento2.git
```

Then update your composer.json with the sample data package.
From the Docs ->

Add "minimum-stability": "beta", before license which now looks like

```
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "Magento project (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"minimum-stability": "beta",
"version": "1.0.0-beta",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
```

And run `composer config repositories.magento composer http://packages.magento.com` Then `composer require magento/sample-data:~1.0.0-beta`

And now that your sample data package is installed, update your database with

`<path to Magento 2 bin dir>/magento setup:upgrade`

`<path to Magento 2 bin dir>/magento sampledata:install <your Magento administrator user name>`

Comment: <path to Magento 2 bin dir>/magento setup:upgrade this command not working. please help to me how to can work ?

Comment: From you project root, the `bin` directory will be under the `app` directory. Inside is the php file `Magento` which loads the Magento CLI application. Do you see it? Can you extrapolate on how it's `not working`?

Comment: problem with mangento2 git branch. I have installed develop branch, develop brach not working installation sample-data. working in magento master brach but command is <magento root directory > php bin/magento magento setup:upgrade command.

Answer (score 3):

First install magento2. After just run following command to install sample data.

1) Goto your installation directory:

```
root@prince:/var/www/html/magento2#
```

2) After, Run this command

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

3) Now login to magentocommerce to get username and password

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer/account/login/

4) Go to developers->Secure keys, Generate new key or use existing key

-> Use **public key as Username** and **Private key as Password**

5) Now run this command for recompile code, upgrade database and clear cache

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now run this command for reindex

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

At last give permission of files and folders

Answer (score 3):

This is simple you can use by the composer , just need go on the root directory and

use below command to download sample data:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Then install sample data

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

you can also clean the cache or do re-indexing if data not showing on the website .

using below commands :
php bin/magneto  indexer:reindex

Comment: Seems the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187283/4826457)

Answer (score 2):

Did you already solve this? If not, see this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html#instgde-install-sample-enable-after

Answer (score 2):

you can use this alternative :

```
composer config repositories.0 composer https://repo.magento.com
```

and then:

```
bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

you'll be prompted for username/password : use **public_key**/**private_key** from your magento marketplace account

Comment: @abilasher I just did, you can check !

Comment: thank you very much . But there is a problem in that . I already post it there

Answer (score 1):

Magento sample-data installation after magento setup(working in master branch - **Solution works for old version - beta version**).

**Command is working like**

```
<path to Magento 2 bin dir>php magento setup:upgrade

<path to Magento 2 bin dir>php magento sampledata:install <your Magento administrator user name>
```

**Command is like not working.**

```
<path to Magento 2 bin dir>/magento setup:upgrade

<path to Magento 2 bin dir>/magento sampledata:install <your Magento administrator user name>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Deploy Sample Data from Composer Repository**

In the Magento root directory, run following command:

```
# bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

This command collects the dependencies from the suggest sections of the **composer.json** files of modules, which suggest to install sample data

**To deploy sample data from the Magento composer repository without Magento CLI:**

Specify sample data packages in the **require** section of the root **composer.json** file, for example:

```
{
"require": {
    ...
    "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "{version}",
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "{version}",
    "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "{version}",
    "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "{version}"
    ....
}
```

}

Where ***version*** is the version of the packages; it should correspond to the version of the Magento instance.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento2 is very easy to install.](http://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-ubuntu-server/)

Step 1-:
download the source code from [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

Step 2-: Extract the source code on your web root.

```
$ unzip magento2.zip
```

Step 3-:
Install dependencies via composer command.

```
$ cd /var/www/html/magento2/   
$ composer install
```

Step 4-:
Set the require permission and ownership.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/magento2/
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2/
```

Magento2 instance is ready to install.
Open the web browser, use you server ip or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Magento repository in your composer.json file than the above code will not work. Try running

composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com

to add a magento repository in your composer.json file and than run

php magento sampledata:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Run Following command in terminal

php bin/magento sampledata:deploy //to deploy sample data in magento2

php bin/magento setup:upgrade //to upgrade modules and to run setup files

php bin/magento setup:di:compile //to compile files

php bin/magento indexer:reindex //index flat tables and product price

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy // to regenerate static files

Give Full permission to Var Folder 777.

Load site in browser

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for ages with this until I used this method to install sample data. what a tool I am ;)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-clone.html

Answer (score 0):

The following will solve your problem

make sure you're in you Magento install directory and you have write access:
then run step by step

`php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

if you don't have your keys please click [authenticate](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html) and follow to guide to obtain your keys

if you get the following error

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
You must be using the interactive console to authenticate`

then check which directory you in, if your are in the magento installed directory then run

`composer update`

and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

We can install the sample data using terminal after Magento2 installation. We need to Run the below command.

1. php bin/magento c:c
2. php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
3. php bin/magento s:up
4. php bin/magento s:d:c
5. php bin/magento s:s:d
6. sudo chmod -R 777 var var/* pub pub/static/* generated generated/*

For moreinformation, check [How to install sample data in Magento2](https://rb.gy/anwizs)